# Simple HTTP POST in Go with File Upload

Tags: http, go, post, upload

I just need to know an **extremely simple** way to send a file to a remote server using HTTP POST, in Go. I have already tried so many complicated methods with no luck. My curl command is this:

```
curl https://api.example.com/upload \
 --user api:YOUR_API_KEY \
 --data-binary @file.jpg \
 --dump-header apiresponse.txt
```

I would prefer something without using multipart. I would also prefer something which uses io.Reader, so that I can later implement a progress bar easily.

Comment: "I have already tried so many complicated methods with no luck" - can you show what you've tried and what issues you ran into?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open, https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Post

Comment: This was it. `os.Open` This was the missing simplicity that I was looking for. It worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I did it. Thanks to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter) for pointing out `os.Open` which was the missing piece for me.

```
func SendPostRequest(url string, filename string) (string, []byte) {
    api_key := ReadAPIKey("../.api_key")
    client := &http.Client{}
    data, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth("api", api_key)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return resp.Status, content
}

func main() {
    status, content := SendPostRequest("https://api.example.com/upload", "test.jpg")
    fmt.Println(status)
    fmt.Println(string(content))
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to Close() the file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. IMHO Go should have some kind of internal checking for un-closed file handles.